# Add background for tabs in nav-tabs

Tags: css

Here is my example - the css is what I tried.

```css
.active::before li {
  background: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="breadcrumb">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#submitted" data-toggle="tab">Submitted</a></li>
      <li ng-class="{'disabled':dataStatus=='submitted'}"><a href="#pendingApproval" data-toggle="tab">Pending Approval</a></li>
      <li ng-class="{'disabled':dataStatus=='submitted' || dataStatus=='pending'}"><a href="#workInProgress" data-toggle="tab">Work In Progress</a></li>
      <li ng-class="{'disabled':dataStatus=='submitted' || dataStatus=='pending' || dataStatus=='inprogress'}"><a href="#complete" data-toggle="tab">Complete</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-content" style="margin:5%;">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="submitted" ng-class="{'active':dataStatus=='submitted'}">
      Submitted data will be displayed here....
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="pendingApproval" ng-class="{'active':dataStatus=='pending'}">
      Pending Approvals will be displayed here....
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="workInProgress" ng-class="{'active':dataStatus=='inprogress'}">
      In Progress data will be displayed here....
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="complete" ng-class="{'active':dataStatus=='completed'}">
      Completed data will be displayed here....
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here I just want to add background color for the tabs which is available before the activated tab(i.e., A tab which has active class)

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9xf5neyz/30/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Solution is here*

```
Just add this css in your code.

.nav-tabs > li:not(.active) a {
    background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: how can I add one more class here? `.nav-tabs > li:not(.active,.disabled) a` like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead in your css.

```
li.active>a{
    background:yellow;
}
```